# Handle OneToMany field on Formbuilder with collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two entities related by OneToMany field and a have problem with formbuilder

NUCLEI entity

```
class Nuclei
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="datinuclei_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Tag
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="nucleo", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idnucleo", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $codicitag;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->codicitag = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addCodiciTag(Tag $tag): self
    {
        if (!$this->codicitag->contains($tag)) {
            $this->codicitag[] = $tag;
            $tag->setNucleo($this);
        } 

        return $this;
    }
```

TAG entity

```
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codicetag", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $codicetag;

    /**
     * @var Nuclei
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nuclei", inversedBy="codicitag", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idnucleo", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $nucleo;
```

FormBuilder where i wanto to insert/edit Nuclei entites

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('codicitag', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type'   => Tag::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
    ]);
```

Each NUCLEI can have many asociate TAG but i get this error
I don't find any example or documentation about this :((

**Could not load type "App\Entity\Tag": class does not implement "Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface".**

//////// UPDATE ///////

As Dohs suggested i created a ColletionType with entity_type "Tag"

```
    $builder->add('codicitag', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => TagType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'label' => false,
        'mapped' => false,
        'by_reference' => false
    ]);
```

This is TagType class

```
class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('id', HiddenType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Tag::class,
    ]);
    }
}
```

I create input type hidden playing with jquery so i have something like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="nuclei_codicitag_0_id" name="nuclei[codicitag][0][id]" value="9287">
```

Values are passed correctly to the controller, but it throw an error i don't understand

**An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO infonuclei (id, codicetag, attivata, progressivo, idcomune, idnucleo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [9287, null, null, null, null, 23748]:**

I don't want to insert new records on "TAG" entity but only EDIT/INSERT the other entity NUCLEI, there is something wrong on my entity mapping

Comment: Please provide full stack trace of exception and all FormBuilder file.

Comment: Maybe i understand, i should create a TagType class with a formbuilder for the entity "Tag". Is this tutorial the right path? https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html  thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to add this :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('codicitag', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Tag::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'expanded'=>true,
                'multiple'=>true,
                'by_reference'=>false,
        ]);
    }
```